# News feed python script

Tags: python

The task: user-generated news feed:

1. User select what data type he wants to add
2. Provide record type required data
3. Record is published on text file in special format

Types of data:

1. News – text and city as input. Date is calculated during publishing.
2. Private ad – text and expiration date as input. Day left is calculated during publishing.
3. Your unique one with unique publish rules.

Expected result:

```
News -------------------------
Something happened
London, 03/01/2021 13.45
------------------------------


News -------------------------
Something other happened
Minsk, 24/01/2021 20.33
------------------------------


Private Ad ------------------
I want to sell a bike
Actual until: 01/03/2021, 21 days left
------------------------------


Joke of the day ------------
Did you hear about the claustrophobic astronaut?
He just needed a little space
Funny meter – three of ten
------------------------------
```

My code:

```
from datetime import datetime, date
from sys import exit


class Article:
    def __init__(self, title, text, line_width):
        self.title = title
        self.text = text
        self.line_width = line_width

    @staticmethod
    def publish_article(formatted_text):
        with open("all_news.txt", "a") as file:
            file.write(formatted_text)


class News(Article):
    def __init__(self, title, text, city, date, line_width):
        Article.__init__(self, title, text, line_width)
        self.city = city
        self.date = date

    def format_text(self):
        return f"{self.title}{(self.line_width - len(self.title)) * '-'}\n"\
               f"{self.text} \n"\
               f"{self.city}, {self.date.strftime('%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S')} \n"\
               f"{'-'*self.line_width}\n\n\n"


class Ad(Article):
    def __init__(self, title, text, end_date, line_width):
        Article.__init__(self, title, text, line_width)
        self.end_date = end_date

    def format_text(self):
        day, month, year = map(int, self.end_date.split('/'))
        days_left = (date(year, month, day) - date.today()).days
        return f"{self.title}{(self.line_width - len(self.title)) * '-'}\n"\
               f"{self.text} \n"\
               f"Actual until: {date(year, month, day).strftime('%d/%m/%Y')}, {days_left} days left \n"\
               f"{'-'*self.line_width}\n\n\n"


class PersonalNews(Article):
    def __init__(self, title, text, line_width):
        Article.__init__(self, title, text, line_width)

    def format_text(self):
        return f"{self.title}{(self.line_width - len(self.title)) * '-'}\n"\
               f"{self.text} \n"\
               f"{'-'*self.line_width}\n\n\n"


while True:
    user_input = input('Enter a number: '
                       '1 - Publish news;\n'
                       '2 - Publish ad; \n'
                       '3 - Publish personal news\n'
                       'q - Exit\n')
    if user_input == "1":
        new_news = News("News",
                        input('Print your text\n'),
                        input('Print city for the news\n'), datetime.now(), 30)
        new_news.publish_article(new_news.format_text())
    elif user_input == "2":
        new_news = Ad("Private Ad",
                      input("Input your text\n"),
                      input('Print endDate of ad in format DD/MM/YEAR\n'), 30)
        new_news.publish_article(new_news.format_text())
    elif user_input == "3":
        new_news = PersonalNews(input("Input your title\n"),
                                input("Input your text\n"), 30)
        new_news.publish_article(new_news.format_text())
    elif user_input == "q":
        exit(0)
    else:
        print("Incorrect input. Please enter a number (1, 2, 3) or 'q' for exit")
```

Answer (score 1):

### Shadowing

Your `date` parameter to the constructor of `News` is poorly-named, because it shadows the built-in `date` that you've imported from `datetime`.

### Super

Your call to `Article.__init__()` should use `super()` instead.

### Data classes

`Article` can just be a `@dataclass` with its explicit `__init__` removed.

### Static methods

`publish_article` doesn't make sense as a static method. In your invocations, you're always calling `format_text()` on a child instance, then passing that to a static method on the parent. Instead:

- Define `format_text(self) -> str: raise NotImplementedError()` on `Article` to declare it abstract
- Change `publish_article(self)` to simply `file.write(self.format_text())`

### Backslash continuation

Change this:

```
    return f"{self.title}{(self.line_width - len(self.title)) * '-'}\n"\
           f"{self.text} \n"\
           f"{self.city}, {self.date.strftime('%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S')} \n"\
           f"{'-'*self.line_width}\n\n\n"
```

to drop the backslashes and use parens instead:

```
    return (
        f"{self.title}{(self.line_width - len(self.title)) * '-'}\n"
        f"{self.text} \n"
        f"{self.city}, {self.date.strftime('%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S')} \n"
        f"{'-'*self.line_width}\n\n\n"
    )
```

### Date parsing

This is evil:

```
    day, month, year = map(int, self.end_date.split('/'))
```

Instead, you should be using an actual parsing method out `datetime` to get you a `date` instance; then referring to its members. Since you're looking for `DD/MM/YEAR`, this will be:

```
end_date = datetime.strptime(self.end_date, '%d/%m/%Y').date()
# Use end_date.day, end_date.month, end_date.year
```

That said, if you're at all able, drop that date format like a sack of rotten potatoes. YYYY-mm-dd is sortable and unambiguous.

Comment: Thanks a lot, a very useful!